# Run MapReduce Jar in Spring cloud data

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I need to run a mapreduce spring boot application in spring cloud data flow. Usually applications registered in scdf is executed using "java -jar jar-name" command. But my program is a mapreduce and it has to be executed using "hadoop jar jar-name". How do I achieve this ? What would be better approach to run mapreduce application in scdf ? Is it possible to directly register mapreduce apps ?

I'm using local data flow server to register the application.

Comment: Why MapReduce instead of Spark or Beam?

Comment: @cricket_007 May be because that is a constraint forced upon him by his organization. . . Did you ever think of that?

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky Maybe, in my experience, I've only used Oozie / Airflow to execute vanilla `java jar` commands via shell actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SCDF the format of the command to run a JAR file is managed by a deployer. For example, there are local deployer. Cloud Foundry etc... There is/was Hadoop/YARN but it was discontinued I believe. 
Given that the deployer itself [is an SPI](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer) you can easily implement your own or even fork/extend [local-deployer](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-local) and modify only what's needed.

Comment: Here is some additional info - https://spring.io/blog/2018/11/01/project-update-spring-cloud-data-flow-for-apache-mesos-and-apache-yarn

Comment: I'm able to use the hadoop command by modifying the local-deployer code. Thank u so much. But the mapreduce logs are going to stderr.log instead of stdout.log. Do u have any inputs for this ?